# Thingsboard has multilingual capabilities

Tags: thingsboard

Does Thingsboard CE/PE has multilingual capabilities.. I am evaluating TB for one of our client working in multiple countries.

If Not, Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it has 6 languages:

- English
- Spanish
- Italian
- Korean
- Russian
- Chinese

Other languages than English, are only partially translated.

[image: Partially translated example]

Answer (score 0):

The language's a personal configuration. The user logged can choose his language.

They need to:

- Go to `3 dots menu`, top of the right
- Click on Profile
- Choose the language